# When a Hex Warrior uses Charisma to attack, are they using their will?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, roleplaying

This question is in reference to this Warlock archetype:

**Hex Warrior (XGtE 55,56)**

> You gain proficiency with medium armor, shields, and martial weapons. When you attack with [a weapon you touch after a long rest that lacks the two-handed property], you can use your Charisma modifier... for the attack and damage... this benefit extends to every pact weapon you conjure... no matter the weapon’s type.

In previous editions, Wisdom was the driving attribute for willpower. If this is the case, then this leaves me to wonder: Is WoTC suggesting that you are using your charming personality and force of character to command your sword to attack?

Comment: You may want to avoid block quotes if you change the text that much or at least follow procedure for quotes.

Comment: Did I change the text from the rule book? I had copied the quote. My apologies. Thank you for editing my inaccuracy.

Comment: I edited it based on your text, do you want me to put in the text from the book?

Comment: @David Coffron That would be fine. I apologize again, I actually posted this while at work and don't have access to Xanathar's until I get home. I just had this question rolling around in my head for some time...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## This is specifically called out in the feature where this ability comes from.

> **Hex Warrior**
>
> ...The influence of your patron also allows you to mystically channel your will through a particular weapon...

You are channeling your will through the weapon changing the benefit from Strength (your will now determines the force behind the weapon) or Dexterity (your will now determines the accuracy of your attack).

Comment: Ah, so this is similar to what Slagmoth said; in 5e, Charisma and Wisdom seem to combine to form one's will. Thank you for all your assistance in editing and answering this question. The clarification will be helpful for my roleplaying.

Answer (score 4):

My daughter wants to play a Hexblade in our next game because she wants it to be like *Magnus Chase* and his sword *Jack*.  Basically, she wants a sentient weapon (which I see no problem granting her as her Pact Weapon at level 3) which she has to convince to attack in the way that she wants.  ***The better she communicates, the better her blade carries out her will.***

I think her idea for this is fantastic.  Why wouldn't a super powerful entity which manifests in sentient weapons grant a lesser sentient sword for its Warlocks' use?  I told her that she can carry out the conversations between her character and the sword and that there's nothing else special about the sword beyond that (other than what the class provides).

Comment: The Hexblade patron is not a powerful sword, but the force that gives the other powerful swords, such as Blackrazer, its power

Comment: I love this concept for your daughter's character. I am not familiar with Magnus Chase... What is that from?

Comment: Rick Riordan wrote the *Percy Jackson* series.  It delved into Greek mythology and then Roman.  He wrote a separate series about Egyptians and then a follow-on (kind of) to Percy Jackson concerning the Norse: *Magnus Chase*.  *Jack* is an ancient, sentient, and very powerful sword with a long name.  Rick Riordan likes to make this more approachable and funny by giving old things new names.  They're great series for kids and adults to read together or separately.  I was sad when she finally decided to read them without me (it's much faster for her that way).

Comment: @NickBrown Great answer, love your daughter's approach on this, and I miss reading to/with my kids.